# Entity framework 4 - Number of active connections

Tags: c#, sql, database, performance, entity-framework

I have an old application which is using Entity framework 4(ObjectContext). EF 6 has DbContext.

In EF4 I can explicitly open database connection and do something like as below

```
using(var context = new EmployeeContext)
{
context.Connection.Open();
// and then here I am accessing some database objects
// and then calling context.SaveChanes();
}
```

Also in some other files I have code like as below. code did not call context.Connection.Open();

```
using(var context = new EmployeeContext)
{
// here I am accessing some database objects
// and then calling context.SaveChanes();
}
```

I know both of above will work.Application is used by quite a number of users(around 1200 concurrent users at some time).

Now I went to my database server and ran below query during peak time usage of my application

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
dbid, loginame
```

It showed around some 5000 open connections at that time and that is when I am thinking; Is it because of 
context.Connection.Open() as code is not explicitly calling context.Connection.Close() and because of this connection is still opened and this is increasing load on database server. Though context.Connection.Open() is enclosed inside using block.

Thoughts please?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at this code

```
using(var context = new EmployeeContext)
{
    context.Connection.Open();
    // and then here I am accessing some database objects
    // and then calling context.SaveChanes();
}
```

As soon as `context` goes out of scope of the using statement, context.Dispose() is called, which in turn closes the connection.

The explicit call to .Open() does not require an explicit call to .Close(), though you do want to make sure you leave the using block as soon as you no longer need the connection to be open.